# How to create "DNS entries" for localhost kubernetes ingress hosts?

Tags: kubernetes, dns, localhost, kubernetes-ingress

I have ingress-nginx configured with ingress resources that are host specific so how can I access http://appX.my.example.com both from my desktop browser and also from within other pods inside the cluster, that also need to access http://appX.my.example.com?

I'm running kubernetes locally using [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) in a docker container on windows. I'm guessing the exact same question would apply for minicube, k3s or whatever. I'm running this on Windows with Docker for-win and WSL2 (which may not matter).

One solution that I've found is to see what the IP address `host.docker.internal` resolves to (currently `192.168.1.100`) and then create entries like this in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`:

```
192.168.1.100   appx.my.example.com
192.168.1.100   appy.my.example.com
```

Now http://appX.my.example.com resolves correctly both in the desktop browser and for `appY`. Everything works. Two problems with this:

- E.g. after reboots, after starting a VPN and for other black-magic reasons, `host.docker.internal` changes IP addresses "sometimes"
- It is not possible to create a `*.my.example.com` entry in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` (or linux `/etc/hosts` either).

This leads to a need to maintain the `hosts` file which is error-prone and annoying.

Is there a better way? What is the easiest way to develop with kubernetes on localhost if we want to use named hosts in ingress rules?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use? What do you mean that host.docker.internal changes IP addresses "sometimes"? Did you see [this page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)?

Comment: kind currently installs version 1.21. I think `host.docker.internal` is constant while docker is running (remember: "kind" stands for "Kubernetes in Docker"). However, if I restart docker (and hence kind/kubernetes) after enabling/disabling VPN or after a reboot, `host.docker.internal` is prone to getting a new IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've come up with:

I've created a wildcard certificate in a real DNS entry in a domain I own. Something like

```
*.local.mydomain.dk. IN A 127.0.0.1
```

Now the trick is to get coredns (the DNS server in the kubernetes cluster) to resolve `*.local.mydomain.dk` to a `CNAME host.docker.internal`. To do that, I've modified both the configmap and deployment called `coredns` in the `kube-system` name space:

```
diff -u configmap.yaml.orig configmap.yaml
--- configmap.yaml.orig 2021-08-10 00:24:29.234095600 +0200
+++ configmap.yaml  2021-08-10 00:24:37.664095600 +0200
@@ -7,6 +7,7 @@
            lameduck 5s
         }
         ready
+        file /etc/coredns/mydomain.dk.db local.mydomain.dk
         kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
            pods insecure
            fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
@@ -21,6 +22,11 @@
         reload
         loadbalance
     }
+  mydomain.db: |
+    local.mydomain.dk.   IN SOA   sns.dns.icann.org. noc.dns.icann.org. 2015082541 7200 3600 1209600 3600
+    local.mydomain.dk.   IN NS    a.iana-servers.net.
+    local.mydomain.dk.   IN NS    b.iana-servers.net.
+    *.local.mydomain.dk. IN CNAME host.docker.internal.
 kind: ConfigMap
 metadata:
   creationTimestamp: "2021-08-09T21:58:26Z"
```

```
diff -u deployment.yaml.orig deployment.yaml
--- deployment.yaml.orig    2021-08-10 00:26:17.324095600 +0200
+++ deployment.yaml 2021-08-10 00:25:57.584095600 +0200
@@ -108,6 +108,8 @@
           items:
           - key: Corefile
             path: Corefile
+          - key: mydomain.dk.db
+            path: mydomain.dk.db
           name: coredns
         name: config-volume
 status:
```

Now `whatever.local.mydomain.dk` resolves to `127.0.0.1` in the browser and to `host.docker.internal` inside pods. Bingo!